# Laravel Form Model Binding editing array values

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-5.4

Create form works fine with the following code:

```
<div class="span3">
              {!! Form::input('text', 'tactic[]', null, array('id' => 'tactic', 'class' => ' form-control TabOnEnter', 'placeholder' => 'Tactics_1')) !!}
          </div>
<div class="span3">
              {!! Form::input('text', 'tactic[]', null, array('id' => 'tactic', 'class' => ' form-control TabOnEnter', 'placeholder' => 'Tactics_1')) !!}
          </div>
<div class="span3">
              {!! Form::input('text', 'tactic[]', null, array('id' => 'tactic', 'class' => ' form-control TabOnEnter', 'placeholder' => 'Tactics_1')) !!}
          </div>
```

This will store data in db like this: ["ui","iu","jh"]

So while editing this form shows error:

```
htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\project\resources\views\dashboard\Test\edit.blade.php)
```

I know this is because its not properly outputs array.
FYI: in my model im using this

```
protected $casts = [
    'tactic' => 'array',
    ];
```

Any way in showing the values from db in edit form.